# How to show and hide loader while using fetch in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using JavaScript Fetch to access an API and I want to show a loader while the fetch is in progress. I'm using the following code...

```
      async function fetchStates() {
            showLoader();
            await fetch('https://localhost:7123/locations/states?token=@{@HttpContext.Session.GetString("sessionToken")}')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(states => {
                for (let i = 0;i < states.length;i++){
                    let option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = states[i].name;
                    option.value = states[i].id;
                    ddlCAStates.appendChild(option)
                }
                /*hideLoader(1);
                scrollToTop(1);*/
            })
            .catch(error => {
                divErrors.style.display = "block";
                let errorName = GetHttpErrorName(error.toString());
    
                txtErrors.textContent = 'The server responded with error: ' + error + ' ' + errorName;
                /*hideLoader(2);
                scrollToTop(2);*/
            })
            .finally(() => {
                hideLoader();
                scrollToTop();
            });
        }

    function showLoader() {
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideLoader() {
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function scrollToTop() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
    }
```

The loader displays for a split second and then hides way before the fetch is completed. The loader should be visible until either the fetch successfully loads data or it fails for any reason. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `await promise.then().then()` etc is usually bad practice - though, probably not your issue, but it makes the code less readable than it should be

Comment: if you remove `async` and `await`, your code should run exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try-catch-finally with async/await

```js
async function fetchStates() {
      showLoader();
      try{
       console.log("fetching starts");
       const res = await mock();
       const states = await res.json();
       console.log("fetching completes");
       console.log("states:", states);
      }catch(error){
        console.log(error.toString());
      }finally{
        hideLoader();
      }
  }
 function mock(){ return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({ json:() =>  Promise.resolve([1,2,3]) }), 2000)) }
 function showLoader(){ console.log("loader showes") }
 function hideLoader(){ console.log("loader hides") }
 
fetchStates();
```

Comment: I've tried this but there is no change.

Comment: do you `hideLoader` except the `finally()`, or change the style of loader, or remove the loader somewhere. you can annotate any suspicious codes to focus on the fetch logic

Comment: I found out that there was an event attached to the loader which was causing it to fade out, upon commenting out that portion of code my original code ran flawlessly however I'm marking this as Answer cause it is a correct one.